# Eddy current speedometre in bicycles

Tags: electromagnetism

I came across a question that is discussing about how speedometres on bikes work by using electromagnetic induction. They then proceeded to ask what would happen to the speedometer reading if the tyre was not fully inflated. I thought that the radius would reduce and so would the velocity as v=2(pi)r/t. However the velocity reading on the speedometer would be more. I don't understand how is that possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the radius of the wheel and tyre is smaller then the circumference is reduced.
To travel a given distance the under inflated wheel would rotate more times than an inflated wheel ie it would be rotating faster at the place where the speedometer was monitoring.
Thus the speedometer reading would be larger.

Comment: Does that mean that for eg that when the tyre is fully inflated to cover a certain distance there would be lets say 10 revolutions, however when its not fully inflated, the revolutions would increase for eg to 15 to cover the same distance so the angular velocity would increase?

Comment: That is correct for a given linear speed of the bicycle the angular speed will be faster for a wheel of smaller radius.